# Rendering objects with and without bind texture

Tags: ios, iphone, opengl-es, rendering

The first object is a frame and the second one is a rectangle that contains an image that is bounds to it.

My code doesn't work properly.

The objects did not appear, if I draw them both, but if I draw only one of either of them it works.

This code is implemented on the render function:

```
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadMatrixf(_projectionMatrix);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);

    //Object frame

        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, frameVertices);

        glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
        glColorPointer(4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, frameColors);
    glMultMatrixf(markerInfo[0].transform);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 72);


    //Object with binded texture

    NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"map" ofType:@"png"];
    GLKTextureInfo* textureInfo = [GLKTextureLoader textureWithContentsOfFile:filePath options:nil error:nil];

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);

    glBindTexture(textureInfo.target, textureInfo.name);

        glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, textureVertices);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, textureCoords);

    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, normals);

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

Comment: try delete glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
and place glEnableClientState  GL_VERTEX_ARRAY and GL_NORMAL_ARRAY before second draw. And use glGetError to identify your problem https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glGetError.xml

Comment: it doesn't work, objects didn't appear..

Comment: did you tried to check errors?

Comment: it won't build if there's an error right?
now it's working because I removed the glcolorpointer and used another texture instead as colour to the other object..

Comment: no, it can be build anyway. so you did not get how to use glGetError?